# Displaying JSON encoded Error Messages with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

I have a form as below, and I used angularJs SPA for this application. This is the one form of my SPA among lot of forms.I need to point out how to display error messages responded from corresponding php process file via angularJs

My lends.php page is below,

```
<?php


$userid= $_POST['userid'];
$copyid = $_POST['copyid'];



//$set_success = array($userid,$copyid);
require_once '../../../core/database/connect.php';
$errors = array();
$data = array();
//.... queries......

if(empty($userid) || empty($copyid)){
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = "Fill both fields";
}else if($numrows == 0){
    //internal codes ...........
}else{
$enterdeal = "INSERT INTO   user_lends_copies(id,user_id,copy_id,date_lend,due_date,status) VALUES   (NULL,'$userid','$copyid','$dateb','$dated','open')";
if($connection->query($enterdeal) === TRUE){
      $data['success'] = true;
      $data['message'] = "New record created successfully";
}else{
    $errors = $connection->error;
                    $data['success'] = false;
                    $data['errors']  = $errors;
                }
                $connection->close();


    if( !empty($errors)) {
    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
   } else {
    // if there are no errors, return a message
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }
 }



echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

And here is my app.js file

```
dash.controller('lendingController',['$scope','$log','$http',function($scope,$log,$http){
$scope.formData = {};

$scope.processFormLends = function(){
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../admin/pages/processing/lends.php",
        data: $.param($scope.formData),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    })

    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);

        if(data.success == false){
            $scope.errorCopy = data.errors;
        }else{
            $scope.message = data.message;
            $scope.errorCopy= "";
            $scope.errorUser = "";
        }
      });
    };

 }]);
```

// PS: Top of the SPA index page I have like below //

```
<body ng-app="dash">
```

And I have attached my lending page,(view page of the app) below,

```
div class="dashtitle">
<h2>Lending</h2>
</div><br/>
<h4>Lend book</h4>
<form  ng-submit="processFormLends()">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorCopy }">
        <label for="Title">Copy ID:</label>
        <input type="number" ng-minlength="1" class="form-control" name="copyid" ng-model="formData.copyid">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorCopy">{{ errorCopy }}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorUser }">
        <label for="Title">User ID:</label>
        <input type="number" ng-minlength="1" class="form-control" name="userid" ng-model="formData.userid">
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="errorUser">{{ errorUser }}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <span id="errMessage" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</span>
    <span id="errMessage" ng-show="data">{{ errorCopy }}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Lend Book" class="form-control blue" name="submit" ng-click=".success()">
  </div>
</div>
</form> 
<pre>{{ formData }}</pre>
```

And I have getting corresponding error messages successfully in Console log, but it is not displayed on the browser page. And Only when no error messages and have only a success message the "Success!" message is displayed. Please give me a tip to correct this! Big help!

Comment: You have few inconsistencies in the template - e.g. displaying {{ errorCopy }} but only show if data is truthy (ng-show="data"). Correct those and you should be fine

Comment: thank you I corrected it and worked perfectly!

Comment: Cool, either close this question then, add an answer (and accept it yourself) or let me know to add an answer. This is so this question doesn't hang around as "unanswered".